# "What do you dream of?" versus "What do you dream of doing?"

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am not sure if "what do you dream of" or "What do you dream of doing?" is the right question for the following response. I know both forms are grammatical, but I suspect only one is natural.

A: What do you dream of? / What do you dream of doing?
B: I want to score 900 on the TOEIC test. / I want to be an astronaut.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker of English, but I take the latter to mean what you specifically dream of doing in the future, your goals. I interpret the former as a more general question about an idea that you wish would become reality, such as (your own) fame, or something on a bigger scale like peace on Earth.

Comment: i think both work, but means slightly different. "what do you dream of" means "you dream of what?" "What do you dream of doing?" means "you dream of doing what?" hope this help.

Comment: Both are natural and idiomatic, but since _score_ is an action verb, it matches better with _"What do you dream of **doing**?"_ than with _"I want **to be** an astronaut."_ It's important to understand the difference between _doing_ something like scoring 900 and _being_ something like an astronaut.

Comment: As a native English speaker, you seem to be correct as is- the first sounds like a more abstract what do you want to happen, while the latter is the more personal what do YOU want to do.

Comment: @Imperator You write: _"As a native English speaker, you seem to be correct..."_, but it's clear that the OP is _not_ a native English speaker!

Comment: @PEDant I know, I was simply attempting to provide perspective outside a fully fledged answer. I'm sorry if I formatted it in a way that insinuated Apollyon was a native English speaker.

Comment: @P.E. Dant Sometimes, the grammar of common English language usage itself doesn't live up to the standards of that logic, as in: A: "What do you _do_?" B:"I'_m_ an astronaut."

Comment: @AshwinSchumann Of course it doesn't, and the question _"What **are** you?"_ is absurdly open-ended! The vernacular often falls short of the ideal, but I suspect that an understanding of this kind of distinction is exactly what the TOEIC assesses.